# Account Management extension for Joomla

Tags: extensions

Suppose I am operating share trading business and have thousands of clients. Is there any extension that helps me take care of accounting needs as well in addition to functions of customer relationshop managemnet (CRM) like name of clients, address, phone no etc.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this can help [Joomla Book Keeping](http://www.joomlabookkeeping.com/). You can Google Php based open source scripts which you can implement and integrate into Joomla

Comment: Joomla Book Keeping is project that made me really excited but appears that the same is no more active. Could you suggest few alternatives?